# Reading the selected value from asp:RadioButtonList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, event-handling, radio-button

I've got code similar to the following...

```
<p><label>Do you have buffet facilities?</label>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="blnBuffetMealFacilities:chk" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList></p>
<div id="HasBuffet">
  <p><label>What is the capacity for the buffet?</label>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radBuffetCapacity" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 30 guests" value="0 to 30"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 50 guests" value="30 to 50"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 75 guests" value="50 to 75"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 100 guests" value="75 to 100"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 150 guests" value="100 to 150"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 250 guests" value="150 to 250"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Suitable for upto 400 guests" value="250 to 400"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList></p>
</div>
```

I want to capture an event when the radio list blBuffetMealFacilities:chk changes client side and perform a slide down function on the HasBuffet div from jQuery. What's the best way to create this, bearing in mind there are several similar sections on the page, where I want questions to be revealed depending on a yes no answer in a radio list.

Comment: On usability: Probably you should think about the listitem texts. A place with for example 40 places would probably select "upto 30" because the can not serve up to 50, but the values in your list would indicate that the upto50 was the right choice....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

this:

```
$('#rblDiv input').click(function(){
    alert($('#rblDiv input').index(this));
});
```

will get you the index of the radio button that was clicked (i think, untested) (note you've had to wrap your RBL in #rblDiv

you could then use that to display the corresponding div like this:

```
$('.divCollection div:eq(' + $('#rblDiv input').index(this) +')').show();
```

Is that what you meant?

Edit: Another approach would be to give the rbl a class name, then go:

```
$('.rblClass').val();
```

Comment: Nice work - how would I get the selected value rather than the index of the input?

Comment: Because of the stupid way that WebForms builds the controls, I used jQuery to assign classes to the inputs/checkboxes and then used $('.classname').val() to get the currently selected value.

Comment: you can always change the clientidmode to static, then your id's stay the same

Answer (score 88):

The simple way to retrieve checked value of RadioButtonList1 is:

```
$('#RadioButtonList1 input:checked').val()
```

Edit by Tim:

where `RadioButtonList1` must be the ClientID of the RadioButtonList

```
var rblSelectedValue = $("#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input:checked");
```

Comment: i tried it but not work but i use same search criteria in another way and it work : alert($('#<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val());

Comment: Yes, we must get the ClientID first. And jQuery style is: var clientId = '<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientId%>'; $('#'+clientId+' input:checked').val()

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="Intent">
  <asp:ListItem Value="Confirm">Yes!</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Postpone">Not now</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="Decline">Never!</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=Intent.ClientID%>").change(function(){
   var rbvalue = $("input[name='<%=Intent.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();

   if(rbvalue == "Confirm"){
    alert("Woohoo, Thanks!");
   } else if (rbvalue == "Postpone"){
    alert("Well, I really hope it's soon");
   } else if (rbvalue == "Decline"){
    alert("Shucks!");
   } else {
    alert("How'd you get here? Who sent you?");
   }
  });
});
```

The important part:
**$("input[name='<%=Intent.UniqueID%>']:radio:checked").val();**

Answer (score 6):

According to me it'll be working fine...

Just try with this

```
   var GetValue=$('#radiobuttonListId').find(":checked").val();
```

---

> The Radiobuttonlist value to be stored on GetValue(Variable).

Answer (score 4):

A Radio Button List instead of a Radio button creates unique id tags name_0, name_1 etc. An easy way to test which is selected is by assigning a css class like

```
var deliveryService;
$('.deliveryservice input').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        deliveryService = this.value
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("input[name='<%=RadioButtonList1.UniqueID %>']:checked").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

following is the code we eventually created. A breif explanation first. We used a "q_" for the div name wrapped around the radio button question list. Then we had "s_" for any sections. The following code loops through the questions to find the checked value, and then performs a slide action on the relevant section.

```
var shows_6 = function() {
  var selected = $("#q_7 input:radio:checked").val();
  if (selected == 'Groom') {
    $("#s_6").slideDown();
  } else {
    $("#s_6").slideUp();
  }
};
$('#q_7 input').ready(shows_6);
var shows_7 = function() {
  var selected = $("#q_7 input:radio:checked").val();
  if (selected == 'Bride') {
    $("#s_7").slideDown();
  } else {
    $("#s_7").slideUp();
  }
};
$('#q_7 input').ready(shows_7);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#q_7 input:radio').click(shows_6);
  $('#q_7 input:radio').click(shows_7);
});

<div id="q_7" class='question '><label>Who are you?</label> 
  <p>
    <label for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMainPane_Body_ctl00_ctl00_chk_0">Bride</label>
    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMainPane_Body_ctl00_ctl00_chk_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentMainPane$Body$ctl00$ctl00$chk" value="Bride" />
  </p> 
  <p>
    <label for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMainPane_Body_ctl00_ctl00_chk_1">Groom</label>
    <input id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentMainPane_Body_ctl00_ctl00_chk_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentMainPane$Body$ctl00$ctl00$chk" value="Groom" />
  </p> 

</div>
```

The following allows us to make the question mandatory...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mandatory_q_7 = function() {
  var selected = $("#q_7 input:radio:checked").val();
  if (selected != '') {
    $("#q_7").removeClass('error');
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#q_7 input:radio').click(function(){mandatory_q_7();});
});
</script>
```

Here's an example of the actual show / hide layer

```
<div class="section" id="s_6"> 
    <h2>Attire</h2> 
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ratingButtons").buttonset();

    });
 </script>


<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"
            AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSizes"     DataTextField="ProdSize"
            CssClass="ratingButtons" DataValueField="_ProdSizeID" Font-Size="X-Small" 
            ForeColor="#666666">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: This is only availabel if you use jQuery UI....http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Answer (score 1):

Why so complex?

```
$('#id:checked').val();
```

Will work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution, try this:

```
var Ocasiao = "";    
$('#ctl00_rdlOcasioesMarcas input').each(function() { if (this.checked) { Ocasiao = this.value } });
```

Comment: thats a terrible idea, addressing the rbl by client id. You dont have control over the id. What happens if, in the future, you nest the rbl in a panel? Your id will be different and your js will break. fail.

Comment: You can generate JS: <%=blnBuffetMealFacilities.ClientId%>

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Bullock solution works just fine, I just wanted to show you mine and add a warning.

//Works great

```
$('#<%= radBuffetCapacity.ClientID %> input').click(function (e) {
   var val = $('#<%= radBuffetCapacity.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val();
   //Do whatever
});
```

//Warning - works in firefox but not IE8 .. used this for some time before a noticing that it didnt work in IE8... used to everything working in all browsers with jQuery when working in one.

```
$('#<%= radBuffetCapacity.ClientID %>').change(function (e) {
   var val = $('#<%= radBuffetCapacity.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val();
   //Do whatever
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted for Vinh's answer to get the value.

If you need to find the corresponding label, you can use this code:

`$('#ClientID' + ' input:checked').parent().find('label').text()`

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, my JS was in a separate file, so using a ClientID response output wasn't conducive.  Surprisingly, the solution was as simple as adding a CssClass to the RadioButtonList, which I found out on [DevCurry](http://www.devcurry.com/2011/01/selected-value-of-aspnet.html)

Just incase that solution disappears, add a class to your radio button list

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="rbl" runat="server" class="tbl">...
```

As the article points out, when the radio button list is rendered, the class "tbl" is appended to the surrounding table

```
<table id="rbl" class="tbl" border="0">
<tr>...
```

Now because of the CSS class that has been appended, you can just refer to input:radio items within your table, based on the css class selector

```
$(function () {
            var $radBtn = $("table.tbl input:radio");
            $radBtn.click(function () {
                var $radChecked = $(':radio:checked');
                alert($radChecked.val());
            });
        });
```

Again, this avoids using the "ClientID" mentioned above which I found messy for my scenario.  Hope this helps!