# jquery to get radiobutton selection

Tags: jquery

I am learning jquery and can't seem to find what I need to get the value of the selected radio button from a radio button list in asp.net radiobuttonlist.

Here is the markup;

```
 <fieldset style="width:50%;">
        <legend>Select one option below</legend>
        <div id="radioContactTasks">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAddEditContact" runat="server"
                         RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
                         CssClass="registerradio" TextAlign="Left">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Add New Contact" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Edit Existing Contact" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Delete Existing Contact" />
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

I've tried various methods, none work. Here is the latest variation to just alert me what was selected.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#rblAddEditContact").on("change", ":radio", function () {
            alert($(this).siblings("label").value);
        });
    });
```

Here is the rendered html

```
<fieldset style="width:45%;">
    <legend>Add New or Edit Exisiting Contacts</legend>
    <fieldset style="width:50%;">
        <legend>Select one option below</legend>
        <div id="radioContactTasks">
            <table id="MainContent_rblAddEditContact" class="registerradio">
<tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_0">Add New Contact</label><input id="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblAddEditContact" value="Add New Contact" /></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_1">Edit Existing Contact</label><input id="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblAddEditContact" value="Edit Existing Contact" /></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><label for="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_2">Delete Existing Contact</label><input id="MainContent_rblAddEditContact_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$rblAddEditContact" value="Delete Existing Contact" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it seems you are using special asp tags...

Comment: You need to loop through all your radio buttons and find the one with the property 'checked', I will put together a complete answer in a moment.

Comment: Post the rendered  `html` browser source code here.

Comment: I hope this post helps :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery

Comment: Additionally, your .on function should just be $("#rblAddEditContact").on("change", function () {
            alert($(this).siblings("label").value); 
You don't need to specify a selector

Comment: $('input[type=radio]:checked')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `radio` buttons have `value` like this

```
<input type="radio" value="rdo-1" name="radio1" />
```

then you may try this to get the `rdo-1`

```
$("#radioContactTasks [type='radio']").on("change", function () {
    alert($(this).val()); // rdo-1
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5DZa/1/).

Otherwise, if your `radio` buttons are like this, without a value attribute

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" />
```

then I think you don't need above code because only one `radio` button can be selected in a named group and it's value could be `on` or `off` and in this case `$(this)` inside the handler is always the `checked` one and it's value will be `on`.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5DZa/).

Alternatively, if you need to get the checked value of your `radio` button outside of the `change` handdler then you can use this

```
$("#radioContactTasks input[type='radio']:checked").val();
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5DZa/2/).

P/S: If still now you have confusions then I suggest you to post the source code rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution is

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
```

or little bit longer but the same, should work as well

```
$('input[type=radio]').filter(':checked').val();
```

on whenever you want get it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#MainContent_rblAddEditContact input[type=radio]').change(function(){
      alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

Live Demo here : http://codepen.io/joe/pen/DJleG

Comment: this doesnt work. i edited my original post to include the rendered html