# How to get selected value of list item in radio button list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a radio `RadioButtonList` which has 3 radio buttons, I want to get a boolean value (true or false) when any of the radio button is selected.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID = "test" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="1"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="2"  />
    <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="3"  />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**For ex :- I have selected the first i.e [0] radio button**

```
var radio = $("#test");
var value = $(radio).find("[type=radio]")[0].checked;
```

But didn't work.

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML as the ASP has no bearing on your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve your problem this way:

```
$("#test").find('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
     var value = $("#test").find('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
     alert(value);
})
```

This way you notice when a change happens to your radio buttons and alert the value of the checked one.

Here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvgn0tw8/1/) It's working as you described. You need to apply common names to your inputs. You can do this via:

```
 <asp:RadioButton GroupName="String" />
```

Updated the fiddle with your code + input names.

Comment: @rdorigo The code is not going inside the change function, this is not working

Comment: Have you put a $(document).ready(function() {...}); around it? Do you get any error messages within the console?

Comment: <td colspan="2">
                                    <table id="test">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td><input id="test_0" type="radio" value="1"><label for="test_0">male</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="test_1" type="radio" value="2"><label for="test_1">female</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="test_2" type="radio" value="3"><label for="test_2">other</label></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>

</td>

Comment: Your fiddle has input type radio buttons, but I have taken list items in radio button list

Comment: You need to apply a common name to the inputs. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: I have taken list items but they are rendered as "input", could you please tell me how to apply a common name to the inputs

Comment: You can achieve this through <asp:RadioButton GroupName="String" />

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$("#test").find('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          alert($(this).val())
      }
});
```

Comment: You should replace your double use of $(this) by defining $this = $(this) for exemple

Comment: <td colspan="2">
                                    <table id="test">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td><input id="test_0" type="radio" value="1"><label for="test_0">male</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="test_1" type="radio" value="2"><label for="test_1">female</label></td>
 </tr><tr>
  <td><input id="test_2" type="radio" value="3"><label for="test_2">other</label></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>

</td>

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to get the boolean value(true/false) of radio button when clicked. As a matter of fact, you can only set a radio button which then unsets the other. Hence, you can only return true on on-click event of radio button.

I prefer name-spacing while accessing DOM elements. So, I would do it the following way:

```
$('input[type=radio]', '#test').click(function() {
        return true;
});
```

If you want the specific button reference, you can return it's value as:

```
return $(this).val();
```