# How to select the listitem in RadioButtonList using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbtn" runat="server" >
                                <asp:ListItem Value="firstitem">First</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="seconditem">Second</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I need to set the `First` listitem to be selected based on some condition. Also to deselect based on some condition.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery

Comment: @melvas, Have you read the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider wrapping the RadioButtonList in some element with specific id or class and using that to search the element or setting the property ClientIdMode="Static" to avoid ASP.Net from changing the id.

If all you want is the first to be selected then, find the first radiobutton and select it. I don't know what is your condition that you are speaking of.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
   $("#rdbtn :radio:first").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Select with specific value:

```
   $(function() {
       $("#rdbtn :radio[value='1']").prop("checked", true);
    });
```

Comment: For second radio button, I used `radio:second` but it throws error in my application.

Comment: There is no :second-selector, what is you'r condition to search for the radiobutton? With value? With text?

Comment: With value..For example if value is "first" first radio button is selected and second radio button should not be selected..Similarly vice versa for another condition..that is second radio button is selected if the value is "second"..Thanks..

Comment: My second example does exactly that, finds the radiobutton with specific value and selects that. You should be able to use that method.

Comment: Thank You very much. Second Example is fine. Works as expected.