# jQuery - ASP .NET RadioButtonList control 'Change' event never triggered

Tags: jquery, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a `RadioButtonList` control that is declared like this:

```
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtnlistUnits" runat="server"
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Metres"  Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Feet" Value="Ft"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I want to be able to have the selection affect the features on-screen, but the `change` event doesn't fire with selection of either button.

I originally didn't include the `input` tag in the jQuery selection, and read online just now that this may have been the problem. It has been added but made not change.
I'm not hugely familiar with jQuery in ASP .Net, so I was wondering if the language's `ListItem` control is an alias for something slightly different to `input`.

```
        $('#cSearch #rbtnlistUnits input').change(function() {
            console.info("changed"); //doesn't appear in console
        });
```

If this isn't the case, can anyone spot anything else that might be missing?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: _"I was wondering if the language's ListItem control is an alias for something slightly different to input"_ - you can easily check by looking at the HTML that is sent to your browser (view source). Also check that the ID of the rendered element is actually `rbtnlistUnits`.

Comment: Hi there, when I look at the rendered HTML I get the following:
<td><span><input id="CP2_cSearch_rbtnlistUnits_0"...
for the first radio button. I'm not entirely sure what to do with this as this label isn't used in the code. Does ASP .NET provide some kind of feature that links dynamically? Thanks @Turnip

Comment: set AutoPostBack= true in control and hopes this will work

Comment: Still nothing! From what I have seen on other posts, could this be something to do with the `.ClientID` property that can be used to access HTML elements? @Pramod

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="rbtnlistUnits" runat="server"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Metres"  Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Feet" Value="Ft"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <script>
    $(function() {   
       $('#rbtnlistUnits').change(function() {
       console.info("changed"); 
       });
       });
</script>
```

---

Comment: That will not work.  rbtnListUnits is a server control and ASP will change the id when it renders the page.  You should read over existing answers before posting.

Comment: i just forgot to add ClientIDMode=Static

Comment: Hi there, coming back to this I now have the issue that jQuery doesn't seem to be able to identify the `input` elements nested inside the `RadioButtonList`. Will these also require the "Static" value for this property?

Comment: check this  <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery>