# strange jQuery textbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, vb.net

I cannot for the life of me figure this one out.  I have two javascript functions (jQuery) linked to buttons using the vb.net code behind like such:

```
Button_NewProgram.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return NewProgramEdits();")
Button_SaveSchedule.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return ScheduleEdits()")
```

Both of these buttons are part of a content page with a master page, there is no body or form tags in the content, just a table with no id set.  Both javascript funtions are almost exact, yet for some reason execute VERY differently.  I know they fire because I see the alerts, I use IE v11.  I get NO errors.  The functions are:

I set a mask for all the textboxes in document.ready()

```
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee1.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee2.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee3.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee4.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee5.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee6.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee7.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee8.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee9.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_RegFee10.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");    
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee1.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee2.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee3.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee4.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee5.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee6.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee7.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee8.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee9.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");
$("#<%=Inputmask_Fee10.ClientID%>").inputmask("999");

' This one works, yet the alert shows nothing for the value of fee1 
' and programname yet returns the correct response as all the fees
' are zero and the program IS set to a value ("test').  Strange.

function NewProgramEdits() {
    var fee1 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee1.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    alert("New Program Fee 1 = ") + fee1;
    var fee2 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee2.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee3 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee3.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee4 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee4.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee5 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee5.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee6 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee6.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee7 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee7.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee8 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee8.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee9 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee9.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var fee10 = $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee10.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g,"");
    var newprogram = $('#<%=TextBox_NewProgram.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();
    alert("Program Name = ") + newprogram;

    if (newprogram == '') {
        alert('Enter the program name.');
        $('#<%=TextBox_NewProgram.ClientID%>').focus();
       return false;
    } else if (fee1 == '0' && fee2 == '0' && fee3 == '0' && fee4 == '0' && fee5 == '0' && fee6 == '0' && fee7 == '0' && fee8 == '0' && fee9 == '0' && fee10 == '0') {
        alert('You must enter at least one fee value for a new program, they cannot all be zero.');
        $('#<%=Inputmask_Fee1.ClientID%>').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

For some reason this one does NOT work:

```
    ' The alerts show nothing or empty string even though 
    ' the default values for the textboxes is ALWAYS zero, 
    ' the replace code replaces the mask character with an empty string
    ' the actual value of ALL the textboxes is "0__" (two underscores)

function ScheduleEdits() {
    var regfee1 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee1.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee2 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee2.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee3 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee3.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee4 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee4.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee5 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee5.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee6 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee6.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee7 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee7.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee8 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee8.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee9 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee9.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee10 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee10.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var programtype = $('#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>').val().toUpperCase();

    alert("Fee 1 = ") + regfee1;
    alert("Program Type = ") + programtype;

    if (programtype == 'SCHEDULE' && regfee1 == '0' && regfee2 == '0' && regfee3 == '0' && regfee4 == '0' && regfee5 == '0' && regfee6 == '0' && regfee7 == '0' && regfee8 == '0' && regfee9 == '0' && regfee10 == '0') {
        alert('You must enter at lease one fee value for the schedule program.');
        $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee1.ClientID%>').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

NOTE: Added markup for radiobuttonlist

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="SCHEDULE">Schedule</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="PROGRAM">Program</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ZEROFEE">Zero Fee</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Have you notice that the alerts won't compile? `alert("Fee 1 = ") + regfee1;` is that a typo while copying it here?

Comment: I get no errors, I've always use that code to show var values.

Comment: The alert should be `alert("Fee 1 = " + regfee1);`

Comment: Lol .. duh ... of course ... wow that was quite the brain fart and I was looking at that for hours.  Ok, now the alerts show the value of fee1 but programtype is empty or null string even though a selection is made. and the function still returns true even when all the values are zero.

Comment: You need to get the radio button value like so: var radioVal = $("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>").prop("checked");     The function returns true because programtype will never equal SCHEDULE since you're not getting the value of the radio button correctly. You'll need to check the individual button for SCHEDULE to see if it's checked and use that in your condition.

Comment: Using `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>").prop("check‌​ed");` gets me "Program Type = undefined" ....

Comment: I need the value, there are three possible values, if one of the other two values are selected, the function should return false.

Comment: Try: `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>:checked").val()`

Comment: @Twisty ... using `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>:checked").val‌​()` gets me `SCRIPT1014: Invalid character`, which I assume is the colon.

Comment: You need to use the client ID of the SCHEDULE button, not the button group. Since you've not shown your markup here, I can't tell you what that ID should be. If you post your markup for the radio buttons I can help.

Comment: @mjw ... I added the markup to my answer.

Comment: @Twisty ... I must have had some stray character in the code somewhere.  I deleted and re-entered the code, but `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%>:checked").val‌​(). gets me `"Program Type = undefined" ` ...

Comment: @PrescottChartier now I see the issue, selecting the wrong elements.

Comment: Try: `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%> input:checked").val()` to select the radio element. I think it creates a `<input type="radio" value="">` element, but I am not positive.

Comment: @Twisty ... using `$("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%> input:checked").val()` got me what I needed.  Thank you, if you'll put this in an answer, I'll give you credit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the following code:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="SCHEDULE">Schedule</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="PROGRAM">Program</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="ZEROFEE">Zero Fee</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

To get the Value of the selected radio check, you will want to use `$("#ID input:checked")` to capture the right element. This would look like:

```
var programtype = $("#<%=RadioButtonList_RegFeeMethod.ClientID%> input:checked").val();
```

This should select the proper `<input>` element and allow you to access it's `value` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input name="rdSchedule" type="radio" id="rdSchedule" value="SCHEDULE" />&nbsp;
<label>Schedule</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;                    
<input name="rdProgram" type="radio" id="rdProgram" value="PROGRAM" />&nbsp;
<label>Program</label>
<input name="rdZeroFee" type="radio" id="rdZeroFee" value="ZEROFEE" />&nbsp;
<label>Zero Fee</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ScheduleEdits() {
    var regfee1 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee1.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee2 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee2.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee3 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee3.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee4 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee4.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee5 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee5.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee6 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee6.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee7 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee7.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee8 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee8.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee9 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee9.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");
    var regfee10 = $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee10.ClientID%>').val().replace(/_/g, "");

    var progTypeSched = $("#rdSchedule").prop("checked");

    alert("Fee 1 = " + regfee1);
    alert("Program Type = " + programtype);

    if (progTypeSched && regfee1 == '0' && regfee2 == '0' && regfee3 == '0' && regfee4 == '0' && regfee5 == '0' && regfee6 == '0' && regfee7 == '0' && regfee8 == '0' && regfee9 == '0' && regfee10 == '0') {
        alert('You must enter at lease one fee value for the schedule program.');
        $('#<%=Inputmask_RegFee1.ClientID%>').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Although I'm sure this code will work, I am, unfortunately, stuck with using RadioButtonList.

Comment: understandable. try this nifty solution to working around the RBL limitations using jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery GL!

Comment: Had I not been so wrapped around the axle with the alerts, I may have found this.  I had been asking the wrong question ... lol ...